# SessionState out of memory exception

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I am getting "Out of memory exception" when assigning values in session variables. 
The session values are maintained in stateserver.
How to increase the size of the session stateserver memory? or any other option?

Thanks,
P.Gopalakrishnan.

Comment: Are you talking about ASP.Net? What are the size of the variables you are assigning to the session variables (and how many sessions are we talking about roughly)?

Comment: YES, we are saving datatable in session. Maximum 3 session.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Couple of quick options:-

1. Use a 64bit system to run the stateserver and give it plenty of storage, this is not necessarily lots of RAM (although that helps performance) but a seriously oversized Pagefile would do, use a speedy RAID set up to minimise the impact of the paging.
2. Use a SQL server based state store instead.

Answer (score -1):

Every object which you store in session is serializable?

Avoid to add null object in session. It will fail while deserializing.